# Is it possible to specify a new source for an existing Scanner object?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For the following code:

```
String line = new String("Hello World!");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
```

I'm trying to change the source for `scan` from `line` to another String. Is there any way to specify a new source for a Scanner object without having to close it and create a new object with a new source?

---

EDIT:

In the program that uses this code, I use a buffered stream to read text line-by-line into the program, use a Scanner object to pick out the individual words, convert each word using the `shiftWord` method, and use another buffer to write it out to a separate file.

```
try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream(this.fileRead)) {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader buffIn = new BufferedReader(reader);

        try(OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(this.fileWrite)) {
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
            BufferedWriter buffOut = new BufferedWriter(writer);

            String line = new String();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
            line = buffIn.readLine();
            String token = new String();
            String sentence;
            String message = new String();
            while(line != null) {
                line += "/stop/";
                sentence = "";
                do {
                    token = scan.next();
                    sentence += (shiftWord(token) + " "); 
                } while(!token.endsWith("/stop/")); 
                message += sentence + "\n";
                line = buffIn.readLine();
            }
            buffOut.write(message);

            scan.close();
            buffOut.close();

        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.out.println("IOException: Write Error!");
        }

        buffIn.close();

    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.out.println("IOException: Read Error!");
    }
```

The code compiles fine, however running it causes `NoSuchElementException`at this line:

```
token = scan.next();
```

I did some debugging, and what I found is that the problem lies with:

```
line += "stop";
```

because this line appears inside the while loop after I declare the Scanner.
To solve this, I would have to declare the Scanner after this line, which is inside the while loop.
Yet, I dislike the idea of declaring the Scanner inside the while loop because this will create a new Scanner object with every iteration of the while loop. If possible I'd like to:

- Declare the Scanner object outside the loop
- Update the source for the Scanner object from within the loop.

Basically, *reuse* the Scanner object.

If you can help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: I would also like to pass whitspace, in the same format it takes in the original text file to the text file being written.

Comment: you can just add a new line `scan = new Scanner("a new String blah blah")`

Comment: However doesn't that create a 'new' object? I'm just looking for a way to update the source - I haven't found any methods for that, though. I'm sorry, I haven't been doing this for long, so I don't really know...

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your question, but perhaps it might be better if you could explain the overall problem you are having because this sounds like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the question.

Comment: Try declaring the `line` variable before the scanner.  Move this line to before you initialize the scanner `line = buffIn.readLine();`

Comment: I just tried that. It didn't work.
I also tried moving the line where I initialize the Scanner from outside the loop to inside, and I put it after `line += "/stop/";` and I moved `scan.close();` to the inside of the loop as well.
So now, with every iteration of the loop there is a new Scanner created, and closed by the end of the iteration. This allowed the program to work.
However, this is my problem. I would _like_ to reuse one Scanner object, and just update its source from inside the loop.

I just want to know if there's any way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change Scanner's underlying input stream -- it's designed to read from a single input until it is empty. You could probably wrap the scanner around a SequentialInputStream wrapped around a LinkedList of ByteArrayInputStreams which could then be extended at runtime, but I'm having difficulties imagining a situation where this would be a good idea.

In your case: why not wrap the Scanner directly around buffIn? Configure the Scanner to not ignore newlines as you are using them (`useDelimiter("[\\s&[^\\n\\r]]*")`). This way, you only need to create one Scanner.

EDIT: This example uses word boundaries as delimiters:

```
public class ScannerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner("this   is a  \n\tTest");
        s.useDelimiter("\\b");
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String token = s.next();
            System.out.println("\"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(token)
                    + "\"\tapply shiftToken = " + !token.matches("\\A\\s+\\z"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"this"      apply shiftToken = true
"   "       apply shiftToken = false
"is"        apply shiftToken = true
" "         apply shiftToken = false
"a"         apply shiftToken = true
"  \n\t"    apply shiftToken = false
"Test"      apply shiftToken = true
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. That's a good solution, thank you. I shall try it and respond back with the results. One question: Will the use of the delimiter allow me to carry over the newlines once I have sent individual tokens through the `shiftWord()` method?
(This is the method used in the program to change around the letters in the `token` String.)
I want the text format (newlines, indentations, etc.) in the file that I write to, to match the the text format of the original text in the file that I read from.

Comment: @bookworm No, this delimiter doesn't allow that -- your current solution skips all whitespace except newlines so I assumed you did not need them. However, you can useDelimiter("\\b") to return words and whitespace alternatingly. Please update you question to reflect the fact that you want to pass whitespace through untouched.